# Fastest way to determine how many times a number can be sutracted in a total number, while each subtraction result is greater then another number

Tags: algorithm

Is it possible to solve the following problem without a cycle? By using a math formula. It could make my app much faster.

How many times can 43920 be subtracted in 189503, while each subtraction result is greater than 79920

Example:

```
189503 > 79920 so 189503-43920=145583 (1 time)
145583 > 79920 so 145583-43920=101663 (2 times)
101663 > 79920 so 101663-43920=57743 (3 times)
57743 < 43920 so it means it ran 3 times
This would be the same as 189503-(43920*3) = 57743 or 189503 % (43920*3)
```

I don't know if i wrote my question well, maybe you can help

Comment: If i understand correctly you want `Math.floor( (189503 - 79920) / 43920)` so 2.

Comment: use maths .. `Math.floor((max - min) / divisor)`

Comment: you mention in your title "*while each subtraction **result** is greater then another number*". So the 3rd subtraction in your edit should not count.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli the 1st subtraction should not count. The third or second 101663-43920=57743 does count

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It resumes to: `Math.floor((189503 - 79920) / 43920)`. Which equals `2`.

1. First subtract `79920` to keep only the distance that you really care.
2. Divide the remainder by `43920`. This will result in the "exact" number of times it can be subtracted.
3. Finally, apply a `floor` function to get an integer number.

Comment: 189503 > 79920 so 189503-43920=145583 (1 time) ////
145583 > 79920 so 145583-43920=101663 (2 times) ////
101663 > 79920 so 101663-43920=57743 (3 times) ////
57743 < 43920 so it means it ran 3 times ////
This would be the same as 189503-(43920*3) = 57743 or 189503 % (43920*3)

I don't know if i wrote my question well, maybe you can help

Comment: Hi @IglesiasLeonardo in the original question you said: "while each subtraction **result** is greater than 79920". In your example, the result of the third iteration is `57743` which is lower than `79920` making it an invalid iteration. Thus, the result is 2.

If you need 3, simply do: `Math.ceil((189503 - 79920) / 43920)`(change `floor` to `ceil`). That means the validation is BEFORE the subtraction, not after.

Answer (score 1):

Let x = the number of times you need to subtract by

```
189503 - (43920 * x) = 79920

189503 = 79920 + (43920 * x)

189503 - 79920 = 43920x

x = (189503 - 79920) / 43920

x = 2.49505919854
```

Given that you can not really subtract something any other than a whole number (integer) of times the answer is 2.

Comment: This is easier to understand and is helpful